# OverridesDefaultStyle in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Can any one explain what `OverridesDefaultStyle` actually does to a control? I have read MSDN, but it is not clear.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is used to ignore the default style of a control. By default, if you put a control in your UI, all the properties that are not set locally (explicitly or with a custom style) will take their value from the default style. If you set `OverridesDefaultStyle` to `true`, the default style won't be used

Comment: What's a good example of this? I've tried to use it before, but I don't see any changes when I set it to true.

Comment: One issue solved by setting the `OverridesDefaultStyle` to `true` is `DependencyProperty` value inheritance 
(See [DependencyProperty Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). 
Some styles have properties set, that breaks inheritance. Eg.: if you want the same `Foreground` color within a `ItemsControl`, and then uses a `Button`. The Button style will override the Foreground property and the inheritance will not work.

Comment: So there's no point in setting OverridesDefaultStyle to true on a control if you redefine its control template, right ?