# Removing default styles to start clean on styling in WPF/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

How do you get rid of the default WPF style for a given control? For instance:

If I add a trigger that changes the background color of a button on mouse over, it does so, but then immediately fades into the default blue tint. Is there a correct way to get rid of these so they don't get in the way of custom styles?

Comment: Does this help? http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com.au/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643440/override-default-styling-in-wpf-textbox-based-on-presentationframework-aero) or just take a look on the [OverridesDefaultStyle Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497176/overridesdefaultstyle-in-wpf).
If you have any troubels with the default Style you can simply disable it, but this will make a lot of work because you forced to write all your style behaviors by yourself.